# Project collaboration tool recommendations

Tags: project-management

What project collaboration tools do you recommend for maintaining tasks, bugs, collaborating, messaging, storing files, wiki, etc?

I had a look at Remember The Milk, but not sure if it's ideal!  Backpack looks good and reasonably priced; has anyone used it?

Comment: [List of X questions "aren't really what we want,"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57226/should-we-have-a-list-of-x-close-reason) but it seems they generally should be Community Wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it nice to have one web based project management tool in which I can get an overview of everything related to the project(s). This includes user (developer) administration, wiki, repository and most importantly time tracking with road mapping.

[Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine) does the job for me.

And I normally use a git repository with it. It can be a wee bit difficult to set up on your web server but I found that it was worth the effort.

There's also related questions on stackoverflow like [Project tracking/management tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240/project-tracking-management-tool).

Good luck.

Comment: Redmine looks good, going to give it a try, thanks

Comment: I've been using redmine for a while now and it has been a great asset for us. A number of clients have also expressed they appreciate being able to log in and view a project status at a glance.

Answer (score 2):

I've used [unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com/) which is quite good. It has a ticket based workflow along with git and subversion hosting. 
A single project account is free, with payed accounts being charged by number of projects and amount of storage space used.

Answer (score 2):

The [Atlassian](http://www.atlassian.com/) products are great but not cheap.

- Jira for bug tracking
- Confluence for wiki/collaboration

Pair this with Google App

- Email
- Chat

And you're rolling.

Answer (score 2):

I would personally look into [Mindtouch's](http://www.mindtouch.com/) [products](http://www.mindtouch.com/products). There are even [extensions/plugins](http://developer.mindtouch.com/Deki/Extensions) that are suited to software development teams.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend giving [TeamLab](http://www.teamlab.com/) a try. Maintaining tasks, collaborating, messaging, storing and editing files and wiki are featured. The only thing they lack is bug tracking.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, if you can wait, [Google Wave](http://wave.google.com/) might be a good fit.

Comment: yeah already signed up, nay ideas when its available?

Comment: It doesn't have a release date yet past "later this year".

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of you team (and other factors) a combination of [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/) & [BugZilla](http://www.bugzilla.org/) might suffice.

Of course, Microsoft swears by it's VS Team Systems (haven't used it as the price tag is prohibitive)

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN is comfortable.

Comment: TortoiseSVN has maintaing tasks, bugs, collaborating, messaging, wiki? I know it does subversion integration which can handle the "storing files" requirement, but I didn't think it had any of the other features.

Comment: TortoiseSVN is a task management tool? Anyway it is available for windows...

Answer (score 0):

I would seriously look into [Code Collaborator](http://smartbear.com/codecollab.php)

Answer (score 0):

I've heard of a few teams that use [Basecamp](http://www.basecamphq.com/), but I've always just used [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/).  Trac is opensource and has a decent API for extensions.

Answer (score 0):

[Lighthouse](http://www.lighthouseapp.com) is awesome if you want a hosted solution. It's basically the same as Basecamp, except with a software development focus.

Answer (score 0):

The best I've used so far is SmartSheet (www.smartsheet.com) - I feel like one of those TV salesmen...spreadsheet like interface, stores all size files (and file versions), allows for discussions, alerts and reminders.  Very flexible and easy to use.